# How to return a map catalog from a WPS process with GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wps, catalog-service

I guess everything is in the title, I would like to be able to select a map and have it returned.
This is because I'd like later on to return a GeoTIFF which would have been generated by the server, but I'm making small steps.

I already have a process that works fine on the GeoServer WPS demo, but when trying with other clients, instead of offering me a list of maps I have hosted to choose from, I am asked for a URL. (I have no idea as to what I should enter as URL, and I don't care since it is not very user-friendy...)
I think that the problem here is that GeoServer "cheats" when using his own demo client, because it knows the hosted maps, which other clients don't. I am therefore looking for the way, either for the process to return a catalog of the available maps (if it works), or another solution you could offer me.

Comment: This question should be closed and the content merged with his previous question [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/how-to-return-a-geotiff-from-a-wps-process).

Comment: The previous question appears to be gone already.

Comment: The title question doesn't seem to match the body of the question, do you want to get at a catalogue of maps through WPS, or just a map, or both perhaps through a process like first getting the catalogue and then a map from some reference in the catalogue.  Which other clients have you tried?

Comment: @nmtoken I wanted to be able to send a catalogue of maps for the other end to chose from.

Answer (score 1):

The list of available maps is contained in the WMS capabilities document (assuming I understand what you mean by map)

Comment: Indeed it is, however I wanted to get the maps via WPS. The WMS and WFS services work allright